# Красивое форматирование html, css , js на javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть строки в которых лежит html, js, css, json код. 
Если ли какие нибудь инструменты на javascript чтобы получив такую строку с кодом  отформатировать её по указанному типу? То есть расставить пробелы, переносы строк и.т.д.

Comment: а зачем это нужно? и почему не в отдельных файлах?

Comment: для редактирования кода онлайн.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проект [JS Beautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) позволяет форматировать JavaScript, HTML, JSON. Некоторые параметры можно настраивать.

```
var beautify = require('js-beautify').js_beautify,
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('foo.js', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(beautify(data, { indent_size: 2 }));
});
```

В действии можно посмотреть на http://jsbeautifier.org/

Еще есть проект [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier). Он умеет форматировать:

- JavaScript (включая ES2017)
- JSX
- Flow
- TypeScript
- CSS, LESS и SCSS

У него практически нет никаких настроек - он просто приводит код к виду, который автор считает верным.

В действии можно посмотреть на [https://prettier.github.io/prettier](https://prettier.github.io/prettier/#%7B%22content%22%3A%22hello%20(%20%5C%22world%5C%22%5Cn)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5B%20%5C%22lorem%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22ipsum%5C%22%2C%20'dolor'%2C%20sit(%5C%22amet%5C%22)%2C%20consectetur%5B%20'adipiscing'%20%5D%20%2B%20%5C%22elit%5C%22%20%5D.reduce(%5Cn%20%20(first%2C%20second)%20%3D%3E%20first%20%2B%20second%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22%5C%22)%5Cn%5Cnconst%20Foo%20%3D%20(%7B%20bar%2C%20baz%2C%20things%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%5Cn%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%20style%3D%7B%7B%5Cncolor%3A%20%5C%22papayawhip%5C%22%7D%7D%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%2F%3E%7Bthings.map(thing%20%3D%3E%20reallyLongPleaseDontPutOnOneLine(thing)%20%3F%20%3Cp%3E%7Bok%7D%3C%2Fp%3E%20%3A%20%3CQuax%20bar%3D%7Bbar%7D%20baz%3D%7B%20baz%20%7D%20%7B...thing%7D%3E%3C%2FQuax%3E)%5Cn%20%20%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E%7D%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22printWidth%22%3A80%2C%22tabWidth%22%3A2%2C%22singleQuote%22%3Afalse%2C%22trailingComma%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22bracketSpacing%22%3Atrue%2C%22jsxBracketSameLine%22%3Afalse%2C%22parser%22%3A%22babylon%22%2C%22semi%22%3Atrue%2C%22useTabs%22%3Afalse%2C%22doc%22%3Afalse%7D%7D)